# Windows service setup project custom dialog - how do i get the variables?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, installation, setup-project

Quick question about a windows service, I've added a setup project for my Windows service, and ive added a custom dialog to it, with 4 text fields, but my question is how to i get these informations/variables?

Ive also added an installer for the windows service also, and afterwards the setup project, with the custom dialog.

The informations is something like database connection strings, and so on - so just string values.

This is my code for the "project installer" . the installer item ive added for the windows serive if you wanted to see it.

```
    Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Configuration.Install
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices



Public Class ProjectInstaller

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Component Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        My.Settings.TestSetting = Context.Parameters.Item("PathValue")

#If DEBUG Then

        Dim ServicesToRun As ServiceBase()
        ServicesToRun = New ServiceBase() {New tdsCheckService()}
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)

#Else

        Dim listener As New tdsCheckService()
        listener.Start()

#End If

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
        MyBase.Install(stateSaver)
        Dim regsrv As New RegistrationServices
        regsrv.RegisterAssembly(MyBase.GetType().Assembly, AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub Uninstall(ByVal savedState As System.Collections.IDictionary)
        MyBase.Uninstall(savedState)
        Dim regsrv As New RegistrationServices
        regsrv.UnregisterAssembly(MyBase.GetType().Assembly)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(sender As Object, e As InstallEventArgs) Handles ServiceProcessInstaller1.AfterInstall

    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceInstaller1_AfterInstall(sender As Object, e As InstallEventArgs) Handles ServiceInstaller1.AfterInstall

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should eb able to access them using the Context object.

```
 'Get Protected Configuration Provider name from custom action parameter
        Dim variableName As String = Context.Parameters.Item("dialogSettingName")


  Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal stateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
    MyBase.Install(stateSaver)
```

Comment: There should be an Install event. We basically have a config file associated with the Service. In here we have a number of connection strings. Upon installation the user is prompted to enter these connection strings. We then read them, encrypt them and pop them back into the Config file.

Comment: yeah but i have 2 "afterinstall" events.. which one should i use?

Comment: There should be an OverRidable method. See above:

Comment: strange - i dont have that in my code - could i have done something wrong?

Comment: well i've manually made the method is that correct? and i'll just post the code above

Comment: Looks Good. You can delete the 2 AfterInstall events. Unless you need to do something else after the installation is finished, otheriwse you don't need them. Also, put the following line of code into the intall method. My.Settings.TestSetting = Context.Parameters.Item("PathValue")